# Прокрутка вверх при клике на кнопку слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Пытаюсь сделать одну вещь на сайте. Подключен слайдер Flexslider, инициализирован так:

```
$(window).load(function(){
      $('.textslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshow: false
      });
    });
```

Я бы хотел, чтобы при клике на элемент навигации слайдера `.flex-direction-nav a` страница прокручивалась к верху. Использую такой Jquery:

```
$(".flex-direction-nav a").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  return false;
});
```

Че то не работает так. Может нужно как то один скрипт в другой засунуть,  или еще что-нибудь. Аналогов `scrollTop` использовал уже много, но воз и ныне там. Помогите кто чем может

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не click, а on('click'... Потому click не работает на динамически созданных элементах (не существующих в момент декларации события click).

```
$('.flex-direction-nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Тоже не работает (

Comment: А что в консоли?

Comment: Ничего. Ошибок нет

Comment: Посмотрел работающий код у себя - там body, html. Не помню, почему именно так. Поправил ответ.

Comment: А если точку останова поставить внутри функции? На клик она хотя бы реагирует?

Comment: Да. Внутрь функции слайдера поставил функцию прокрутки и все заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74090/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-).